# How can I get product urls of each store view?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-urls

I have 2 store view:

- `www.example.com` (EN Store)
- `www.example.it` (IT Store)

and I have 2 different urls that point at the same products:

- `www.example.com/car-honda-civic.html` (<--- I want obtain this url)
- `www.example.it/auto-honda-civic.html` (<--- and I want obtain this url)

and I use some php function to redirect the users to the right store based on user's language browser (parsing $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']).

I'm trying to get these links into a separate Magento folder and page:

`www.example.com/myproject/mypage.php`

and this is what I tried to do:

```
// REQUIRE MAGENTO ESSENTIAL CODE
require_once("../app/Mage.php");
umask(0);

// I NEED TO GET ONLY GROUPED PRODUCTS
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$grouped_collection = array();

foreach($collection as $product) {
    if ($product->getTypeId() == 'grouped') {
      //echo $product->getId();  
      array_push($grouped_collection, $product->getId());
    }
}

// E.G.: LOAD PRODUCT 12
$productId = $grouped_collection[12];
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

// I TRYING TO GET PRODUCT URLS OF EACH STORE VIEW
$productLinkEn = $product->getUrlInStore(array("_store" => "en")); 
$productLinkIt = $product->getUrlInStore(array("_store" => "it")); 

echo $productLinkEn; //Output: http://www.example.com/auto-honda-civic.html?SID=2fdsfsd34fsdfsdf34$__store=en
echo $productLinkIt; //Output: http://www.example.it/auto-honda-civic.html?SID=2fdsfsd34fsdfsdf34$__store=it
```

How can I get both clean above urls product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better approach imo would be to look up product url using `core_url_rewrite` table. At least you avoid full product load.

```
    $productUrls = array();
    $idPath = 'product/887';

    $rewrite = Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite');
    $read = $rewrite->getReadConnection();

    $select = $read->select()
        ->from($rewrite->getMainTable(), array('store_id', 'request_path'))
        ->where('id_path = ?', $idPath);
    $data = $read->fetchPairs($select);

    foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {
        if (isset($data[$store->getId()])) {
            $baseUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, null);
            $productUrls[$store->getId()] = $baseUrl . $data[$store->getId()];
        }
    }

    Zend_Debug::dump($productUrls);
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems to work very well. Do you know if I can get in the same way product image urls?

Answer (score 1):

Before loading the product, set the store ID you wish to get product URL for.

`$productUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId)->getProductUrl();`

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. It output something like: www.example.com/mypage.php/catalog/product/view/id/80/s/...

Answer (score 0):

Using Magento methods. This should work... although it could be slow if your catalog is huge. I asume `$stores` is an array of frontend storeIds

```
foreach ($stores as $storeId){

    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);     
    $c = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $c->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
    $c->addUrlRewrite();

    foreach ($c->getItems() as $p){
        echo $p->getProductUrl(); // should print here the SEO friendly url
        $p->clearInstance(); // free memory
    }
}
```